# Firefox addon to view/edit/create localStorage data?

Tags: firefox, firebug, firefox-addon, local-storage

Is there an addon that allows you to view, edit, `localStorage` information?
If there is and it works as an extension of Firebug I will be extremely happy.

Something like Google Chrome's local storage

similar to [Firecookie](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6683/) but for the `localStorage`

[image: Firecookie]
[image: Firecookie]

Is there something like it?

Comment: What I'm assuming was a screenshot of Chrome appears to have died ...

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**FireStorage Plus!**  A great new **FireFox** Addon which is officially recognized by **Firebug** is available from the Mozilla gallery: http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firestorage-plus/

This plugin extends Firebug to give you the functionality you need. As with Firebug itself, FireStorage Plus! is currently under heavy development so new features come out every couple of days...

It is stable and ready for use...

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Firebug is now [deprecated](http://getfirebug.com/), instead enable built-in [Storage Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector) in dev tools settings as said by @Nux below.

Answer (score 58):

You can create, view, and edit localStorage in Firebug, no extension is needed.
http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/DOM_Panel#localStorage
jjb

Comment: This does not alow for easy inspection of localStorage in an iframe that has a different domain

Answer (score 16):

That's easy to dump in built-in Firefox debug tools, just type in console:

```
console.dir(window.localStorage);
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

There is a **new extension that is very useful for seeing and clearing localStorage, en mass**.  It is [Foundstone HTML5 Local Storage Explorer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foundstone-html5-local-storage/).

What's good about it is that it shows ***all*** `localStorage` for every site -- not one site at a time like the other answers to this Q (so far).

Unfortunately, it does not provide an easy way to add or edit `localStorage` values, but that's not too hard in Firefox, anyway.

---

**To Add, Edit, or Delete individual localStorage values in Firefox** (Firebug is not needed):

1. Navigate to the domain in question, for example: http://stackoverflow.com .
2. Open Firefox's console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> in windows).
3. **Set a value** like: `localStorage.foo = "bar"`.  
   Or use [`localStorage.setItem ("foo", "bar")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage).
4. **Change a value** like: `localStorage.foo = "all day"`.
   Or use `localStorage.setItem ("foo", "all day")`.
5. **Delete a value** like: `localStorage.removeItem ("foo")`.

Comment: does not exist anymore it seems :(

Answer (score 10):

I've created a Firefox add-on to provide functionality similar to Webkit's.

You can find the add-on here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firestorage/

Let me know what you think.

Comment: Well, it is not working here, I don't see the values... I'm using FF4B11... And to be perfect it should be a extension for Firebug :P But yea, if it is fixed for FF4 maybe I will use it...

Comment: This would be good, but it can only see the current site at a time -- a major limitation.  As it is, this extension is just a slight coat of varnish over what we can already do from the FF console or the Firebug console.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use the [Storage Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector) of the built-in [Firefox Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) (is disabled by default so you need to [enable it in their settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Settings#Default_Firefox_Developer_Tools) under *Default Developer Tools* > *Storage*).

[image: Storage Inspector option in the Settings panel]

Answer (score 0):

you can also use Steve Souder's Mobile Perf javascript plugin

[mobile perf plugin](http://stevesouders.com/mobileperf/mobileperfbkm.php/)

He gives you a browser link you can click on any website to get javascript debugging tools.

Storager provides local and session storage viewing, It also allows you to export to jdrop website to inspect contents remotely,  which is great for debugging local storage on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "Offline Data" bookmarklet to quickly inspect localStorage, sessionStorage and cookies stored by a web page: http://deceptiveweb.com/blog/examine-offline-data-bookmarklet/