# Worklight JsonStore Error When Using FireFox Developer Edition

Tags: firefox, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I'm currently developing a mobile web app using Eclipse / Worklight v6.2. The app uses the local json store for data storage. When I run my app using FireFox v33.1 and I clear the json store from a function within my app it works exactly as expected. However, if I use FireFox Developer Edition v35.0a2 when I invoke the same function, the local json store is not cleared and I get the following error:

```
"main :: localStoreClear :: Attempting to destroy JSON store..."    
    Uncaught Exception: TypeError: meta is null at (compiled_code):1751" worklight.js:4886
        WL.Logger</__log() worklight.js:4886
        WL.Logger</</PUBLIC_API[priority]() worklight.js:5240
        WL.Logger</window.onerror() worklight.js:5202
    TypeError: meta is null jsonstore.js:1751
```

This is the function within my app that I am calling:

```
/**
 * Destroy the local JSON store and reinitialise it
 */
function localStoreClear() {
    WL.Logger.info("main :: localStoreClear :: Attempting to destroy JSON store...");   
    WL.JSONStore.destroy()
    .then(function() {
        WL.Logger.info("main :: localStoreClear : Destroyed!");

        // Reinitialise store
        localStoreInit();
    })
    .fail(function() {
        WL.Logger.info("main :: localStoreClear : Failed to destroy!");
    });
}
```

From the error message that I receive, it looks like the error is being thrown in the jsonstore.js file? Can anyone tell me if I'm doing something wrong, or if there is a compatibility issue between the FireFox Developer Edition and Worklight?

Many thanks in advance,

Chris.

Comment: While this will likely be looked at, you should note that FireFox Developer Edition is not a supported browser, and I believe it's still in its alpha stages... IBM Worklight does not support it at this time. http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/prereqsForProduct?deliverableId=968A9CE03A2E11E396F9FC10E99BE807#sw-11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

Firefox Developer Edition is not a supported browser. If you encounter this issue on a supported browser, you may want to [open a PMR](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21507639) with steps to reproduce. You may [open a feature request](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014907906&ps=25) to make that browser a supported browser.

**Workaround:**

If you don't mind removing everything inside [HTML5 local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html), this will clear everything JSONStore saves when running in a JavaScript-only environment (i.e. not Android, iOS, WP8 or Win8):

```
localStorage.clear();
```

If you want to be more selective, I believe all the JSONStore html5 local storage keys are prefixed with `jsonstore`. You can look at local storage following these steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6130392/186909).

**Note:** The information above only applies to JSONStore code running on the web browser.