# Firefox 40+: what does the "Found hi-entropy localStorage" message mean?

Tags: javascript, firefox, local-storage

I updated to Firefox 40 today, and I see a neat new message in my Firebug console:

```
Found hi-entropy localStorage: 561.0263282209031  bits http://localhost:8080/my_app_path itemName
```

...where `itemName` is the name of a particular item I've stuck in localStorage.

The referenced line number is always unhelpful: the last one of the main HTML document (it is a single-page app).

Why does this happen? If you'd like an example of my "hi-entropy localStorage", here are the data in question:

```
Object {
 id: "c9796c88-8d22-4d33-9d13-dcfdf4bc879a",
 userId: 348,
 userName: "admin"
}
```

Comment: Do you have Privacy Badger installed by any chance?

Comment: Hmmm, yes. In fact, that was my first thought based on the message, so I disabled it for the site in question. I guess it's time to disable it entirely and see if that fixes the problem. If it does, then Privacy Badger certainly isn't playing very nice--it's not disabling for a site when asked, and it's also not identifying itself in the message. Time to restart the browser, I'll be back in a few minutes.

Comment: So I learned two things today: a) Privacy Badger doesn't respect its settings properly, and b) There is at least one Firefox addon you can (apparently) disable without restarting the browser--because that seemed to work.

Comment: Also annoying: Privacy Badger throws cryptic messages at the console without identifying itself as their source. Thanks @user880772 -- if you post an answer I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your browser has the Privacy Badger plugin (1.0), which can [detect some types of super-cookies and browser fingerprinting](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2015/08/privacy-badger-10-here-stop-online-tracking). It identified your local storage item as a false positive and produced those cryptic logs.

A high-[entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29) string can be vaguely defined as complicated, hard to guess/repeat, or likely to contain meaningful information. If there's such a string in your local storage (in your example, the item id), it's possible that advertisers put it there to uniquely identify you. Privacy Badger has rough methods to estimate a string's entropy, which the developers [discuss here](https://github.com/EFForg/privacybadgerchrome/issues/362).

---

You should check out the paper *[The Web never forgets: Persistent tracking mechanisms in the wild](https://securehomes.esat.kuleuven.be/~gacar/persistent/)*, particularly the section on cookie-syncing:

> Cookie synchronization or cookie syncing is the practice of tracker domains passing pseudonymous IDs associated with a given user, typically stored in cookies, amongst each other.

Comment: Thank you! That's an excellent, clear, concise explanation. I think Privacy Badger needs more people talking about it. I also wish the devs would prefix their log messages--and make sure 'disabled' actually means 'disabled' for any particular domain (including localhost!). :)

Answer (score -1):

I guess is a stranded value. I disabled a script from zopim chat and this started to show. looking for what entropy means I found this explanation "(in data transmission and information theory) a measure of the loss of information in a transmitted signal or message. " which make sense.

You can see what is in Local Storage by opening Developer tools (Ctrl+Shift+S) and enable Local Storage panel by pressing Toolbox option in the right side of the menu bar. 
To delete the value in question, just follow the steps from here [How to view/delete local storage in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084099/how-to-view-delete-local-storage-in-firefox)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I understand what entropy is and (as mentioned in the question, and evidenced by my included `Object`, I know how to manage `localStorage`). It's just a new message that only appeared when I upgraded Firefox, though it's possible it's coming from some add-on (though I hadn't installed anything new).

Comment: I guess I was wrong about not having installed a new add-on. I had recently installed Privacy Badger (see accepted answer) but didn't notice it until the day Firefox 40 arrived, and disabling Privacy Badger (telling it to ignore localhost) was not working.